# How to respond with status 500 (server error) when proxy fails?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

In our test environment we build a one-way proxy service that uses callout to get data from several other services. Now when one of those services fails wso2 proxy sends 202 accepted anyway. Is it possible to "catch exceptions" and return a different status?

I know that in this case it would be better to use a request-response proxy, but even if we would create a proxy that only stores the payload in a messagestore there could be issues regarding database where the payload would be stored (database is down, etc) and we don't want status 202 to be returned if the message was not stored in db.

edit:

Here is my proxy after changes suggested in first answer to my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="notifyOfClaimChangeOut" serviceGroup="" startOnLoad="true"
  trace="disable" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property description="OUT_ONLY" name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default"
        type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
      <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" scope="default"
        type="STRING" value="true"/>
      <property description="OriginalPayload" expression="$body"
        name="OriginalPayload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <iterate description=""
        expression="$body//InsClaimData/PartnerList/PartnerEntry" id="" sequential="true">
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <payloadFactory description="" media-type="xml">
              <format>
                <plat:FindCustomerSync xmlns:plat="http://platform.###.pl/">
                  <plat:request>
                    <plat:FirstName>$1</plat:FirstName>
                    <plat:LastName>$2</plat:LastName>
                    <plat:Pesel>$3</plat:Pesel>
                  </plat:request>
                </plat:FindCustomerSync>
              </format>
              <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/PartnerEntry/BusinessPartner/personData/firstName"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/PartnerEntry/BusinessPartner/personData/lastName"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/PartnerEntry/BusinessPartner/personData/PESEL"/>
              </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="custom">
              <property expression="$body" name="property_name"/>
            </log>
            <callout action="http://platform.###.pl/FindCustomerSync"
              description="QueryCustomersOut"
              endpointKey="gov:###/endpoints/###/QueryCustomersOut.xml" initAxis2ClientOptions="false">
              <source type="envelope"/>
              <target key="QueryCustomersOutResponse"/>
            </callout>
            <log description="" level="custom" separator=",">
              <property expression="$ctx:QueryCustomersOutResponse"
                name="QueryCustomersOut"
                xmlns:cla="http://###.###.io/service/internal/ClaimService" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
            </log>
          </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
      <!-- 
      <callout description="ClaimService"
        endpointKey="gov:###/endpoints/###/ClaimService.xml" initAxis2ClientOptions="false">
        <source type="envelope"/>
        <target key="ClaimServiceResponse"/>
      </callout>
      <log description="ClaimService Response" level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:ClaimServiceResponse" name="ClaimServiceResponse"/>
      </log>
       -->
      <drop/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence>
      <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="500"/>
      <log>
        <property name="Error" value="Fault :("/>
      </log>
    </faultSequence>
  </target>
  <publishWSDL key="gov:###/schemas/###/ClaimService.wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTTP_SC property to send status 500. You'll also need the [makefault mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Fault+Mediator) to construct the fault message.

```
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="500" scope="axis2"/>
<makefault version="soap11">
```

You can refer [this jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3160) to get an idea.

In addition, in the inSequence, you may need to set FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property to move to the fault sequence when a soap fault occurs. Some [explanation available here](http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html).

```
<inSequence>
        <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</inSequence>
```

Comment: Ok, i did set FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT on the begining of the proxy but when i send a non-legal xml it responds with 202 anyway.. So.. it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Also if my endpoint (endpoint to service which my proxy is calling) is incorrect proxy logs errors to console and responds with 202..

Comment: I have added my proxy code after changes you suggested in my first question.

Comment: also, I think you ignored the fact that I'm creating a one-way proxy

Comment: i just checked whether this property works by adding it to an outSequence and it works fine. Please check whether your fault sequence gets executed.

Comment: It does. Log with value "Fault :(" shows up on console just fine, but client gets 202...

Comment: use <send/> or <respond/> in the end and check.

Comment: send at the end of faultSequence did the trick :) thank You so much! :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly i spoked too soon.. It now gives me randomly: 202, 500 and 500 with soapfault (which is not allowed in one way communication). I have tried HTTP_SC=500 and send, HTTP_SC=500 and respond in faultSequence.

Comment: does it happen even when the backend returns the exact same response? if so, looks like a bug.